# Set initial value in Mat-Autocomplete formArray

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, formarray, mat-autocomplete

I have a formArray that's a list where you can add, edit and delete. Everything works fine but I would like to set the initial value for the first two itmes. It works fine for the input value but my mat-autocomplete is not populating correctly. here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-formarray-aqtoke?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts).

**.TS FILE**

```
  initItems() {
    var formArray = this.fb.array([]);

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      formArray.push(
        this.fb.group({
          unititem: ['syed', [Validators.required]],
          age: ['14', [Validators.required]]
        })
      );
    }
    return formArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to init `unititem` with the object option like :

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  formArray.push(
    this.fb.group({
      unititem: [this.options[0], [Validators.required]],
      age: ['14', [Validators.required]]
    })
  );
}
```

Update based on comment:

You can find the name into your array of obect like

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  formArray.push(
    this.fb.group({
      this.options.find(({ itemName }) => itemName === 'syed'),
      age: ['14', [Validators.required]]
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: That works for this example but what it its saved data you are trying to populate. how would you know which option to use if you only know the name

Comment: Thanks is that the only way though. I found this example online but my real issue is the dropdown is coming from  a service that filters as you type.